# Rails Refactoring - Counting Attribute Names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

I have a line of code that counts all attribute names that end in `_cui_id`:

```
cuis_count = self.attribute_names.map { |x| x.include?("_cui_id") }.count(true)
```

What is the best way to refactor this?

Comment: Looks good to me... Don't think I can beat that.

Comment: @rpedroso did below. Curious if anyone else has any ideas. Kind of like how if you do a map on one thing, you can do `.map(&:cui_id)` for example, but I didn't know if there was a shortcut for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count can take a block as an argument:

```
cuis_count = self.attribue_names.count{|x|x.include?("_cui_id")}
```

That saves you a map call